# Why Clang and LLVM is giving math.h error in Mac OS/Xcode

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm

I am trying to build clang and LLVM 9.X on MacOS using source files. I am doing following steps on terminal:

1. git checkout origin/release/9.x
2. cd llvm-project
3. mkdir build
4. cd build
5. cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Xcode" ../llvm
6. cmake --build .
7. sudo cmake --build . --target install

However, when I am enabling CC flag in Xcode, and giving path to clang binary inside build folder, and building code, it is giving me following error:
cmath.h not found
could not build simd.h

Please help, i think I am missing some steps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0B2W.png)